# Problem with add_time function when it has to pass values of sum to print_time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, this exercise asks to add hours, minutes and seconds to see when the movie is gonna be over

Which means - add Start to Duration

Ignore the fact that it is not checking yet if the time is over than 60

It shows an error when I try to pass the values of the summ to print_time it is not reading hours, minutes and seconds of the summ

Thanks in advance

```
class Time:
    """records time of day"""

def print_time(h, m, s):
    print('(%d : %d : %d)' % (h, m, s))

def add_time(t1, t2):
    summ = Time()
    summ.h = t1.h + t2.h 
    summ.m = t1.m + t2.m
    summ.s = t1.s + t2.s
    return summ

def main():
    time = Time()
    time.h = 11
    time.m = 59
    time.s = 30

#check if the print function is working
    print('The time is ', end = '')
    print_time(time.h, time.m, time.s)


    start = Time()
    start.h = 9
    start.m = 45
    start.s = 0

    duration = Time()
    duration.h = 1
    duration.m = 35
    duration.s = 0

    done = add_time(start, duration)
    print_time(done)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output should be 10:80:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a `constructor` to instantiate your class, which is the function `__init__` below and it will save you a lot of headache while debugging your code.
It takes in your attribute when you do `time = Time(11, 59, 30)` and instantiate your `Time` object, then you can use `time` to call functions like `print_time` as `time.print_time()`

As an addition, I would suggest you to go through how classes work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

```
class Time:
    """records time of day"""

    #Use constructor to instantiate class
    def __init__(self, h, m, s):
        self.h = h
        self.m = m
        self.s = s

    #Use class attributes
    def print_time(self):
        print('(%02d : %02d : %02d)' % (self.h, self.m, self.s))


def add_time(t1, t2):
    #Add up time and return a new class object
    h = t1.h + t2.h
    m = t1.m + t2.m
    s = t1.s + t2.s
    return Time(h, m, s)


#Instantiate object of Time class
time = Time(11, 59, 30)

print('The time is ', end = '')
#Use class attribute to call class method
time.print_time()

#Instantiate two more objects of Time class
start = Time(9, 45, 0)
duration = Time(1, 35, 0)

#Pass both of them to add_time, then print time
done = add_time(start, duration)
done.print_time()
```

The output will be

```
The time is (11 : 59 : 30)
(10 : 80 : 00)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `print_time(done.h, done.m, done.s)`.

Answer (score 0):

`print_time(done)` causes an error. as per the function definition it expects 3 parameters, but only one was given here. do `print_time(done.h, done.m, done.s)` instead. Also if you just want to keep track of time, the python datetime module already has a lot of functionality that you don't need to reinvent.